# Plot wide data using pandas and matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, dataframe, visualization

I have the following pandas dataframe:

```
         var    sales
month       
2017-01-01  1   356558.02
2017-01-01  2   295062.54
2017-01-01  3   236702.53
2017-02-01  1   305813.24
2017-02-01  2   348966.32
2017-02-01  3   364121.50
2017-03-01  1   292793.76
2017-03-01  2   345290.65
2017-03-01  3   361361.49
2017-04-01  1   265695.47
2017-04-01  2   351965.57
2017-04-01  3   520796.56
```

How can I plot `month` in the x axis and `sales` in the y axis and three different lines: each one corresponding to a value in the `var` column? I need to represent how `sales` for each `var` changes over time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start by pivoting your data so it's in the form that you want. Then plot.

```
df = df.pivot(index='month', columns='var', values='sales')
df.plot()
```

The pivot gets you this:

```
month        1           2           3
2017-01-01   356558.02   295062.54   236702.53
2017-02-01   305813.24   348966.32   364121.50
2017-03-01   292793.76   345290.65   123456.78
```

From there, the intent should be much clearer.

Comment: yes, thanks it worked, just one additional question, how can i add a vertical line in a specific date for example = '2017-03-23' to this graph?

Comment: I'll defer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17726665/adding-vertical-line-to-date-formatted-time-series-in-matplotlib) about plotting a vertical line with the command `axvline`.